# `onEndReached` not fired into animated ScrollView

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-animated

I'm currently trying to implement an auto-hiding header on my react-native app. Thanks to [this example](https://sketch.expo.io/SJokVF3se) I managed to do so but it broke something. Indeed my `onEndReached` method isn't called anymore when I reach the end of the list. I also used the `RefreshControl` component to implement a `pull-to-refresh` which worked but this `AnimatedScrollView` seems to interfere with the classic ListView functionalities.

I created an `AnimatedScrollView` component like this:

```
const AnimatedScrollView = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(ScrollView);
```

And here is my component's render:

```
<View>
  <AnimatedScrollView
    ...someProps
  >
    <ListView
        ...someOtherProps
    />
  </AnimatedScrollView>
  <Animated.View>
    <Text>My Header Title</Text>
  </Animated.View>
</View>
```

As I said it, I'm pretty sure the `AnimatedScrollView` scroll functionalities are overwriting the `ListView`'s ones but I have no idea on how to fix this...

If you guys have a tip/know a workaround for this or even know a library that could help me for my header, I'd be grateful :)

For those who want to now what do the `someProps` stand for, they're exactly the same as in the example I linked.

Thanks

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, found the solution for it so far?

Comment: Hi man. Nope sorry, we simply decided to remove this from our design and didn't dig further. If you find something let me know ! :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and I have gone with a custom solution of storing the scroll position in `onMomentumScrollEnd` and `onScrollEndDrag` events, measuring the content of ScrollView in `onContentSizeChange` event and calculating myself if the scroll position is at the end of the list. Hope this helps someone having the same problem :)

Comment: Looks like a decent idea :) Thanks for sharing !